# Unable to satisfy superclass

Tags: haskell

I have the following code, and I cannot figure out why I'm getting the first error shown below. As far as I can tell, the `MonadState` instance should be satisfied. Even when I explicitly add in the "non-deducible" instance character for character in the instance constraint, I still get the error. Is this a bug? How can I solve this problem?

Windows GHC version 7.8.3

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Test where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom
import Control.Monad.State


newtype Engine st m a = Engine {
    unEngine :: StateT st m a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState st, MonadTrans, MonadIO)


type instance Zoomed (Engine st m) = Focusing m


-- Same error message even with: (Monad m, MonadState st' (Engine st' m)) =>
instance (Monad m) => Zoom (Engine st m) (Engine st' m) st st' where
    zoom l = Engine . zoom l . unEngine
```

---

```
Test.hs:22:10:
    Could not deduce (mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
                        st' (Engine st' m))
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    from the context (Monad m)
      bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:22:10-62
    In the instance declaration for
      Zoom (Engine st m) (Engine st' m) st st'

Test.hs:23:23:
    Could not deduce (Zoomed (StateT st' m) ~ Focusing m)
    from the context (Zoomed (Engine st m) ~ Zoomed (Engine st' m),
                      mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState st (Engine st m),
                      mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
                        st' (Engine st' m),
                      Monad m)
      bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:22:10-62
    Relevant bindings include
      l :: LensLike' (Zoomed (Engine st m) c) st' st
        (bound at Test.hs:23:10)
      zoom :: LensLike' (Zoomed (Engine st m) c) st' st
              -> Engine st m c -> Engine st' m c
        (bound at Test.hs:23:5)
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `zoom l'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `zoom l . unEngine'
    In the expression: Engine . zoom l . unEngine

Test.hs:23:23:
    Could not deduce (Zoom (StateT st m) (StateT st' m) st st')
      arising from a use of `zoom'
    from the context (Zoomed (Engine st m) ~ Zoomed (Engine st' m),
                      mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState st (Engine st m),
                      mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
                        st' (Engine st' m),
                      Monad m)
      bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:22:10-62
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `zoom l'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `zoom l . unEngine'
    In the expression: Engine . zoom l . unEngine

Test.hs:23:28:
    Could not deduce (Zoomed (StateT st m) ~ Focusing m)
    from the context (Zoomed (Engine st m) ~ Zoomed (Engine st' m),
                      mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState st (Engine st m),
                      mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
                        st' (Engine st' m),
                      Monad m)
      bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:22:10-62
    Expected type: LensLike' (Zoomed (StateT st m) c) st' st
      Actual type: LensLike' (Zoomed (Engine st m) c) st' st
    Relevant bindings include
      l :: LensLike' (Zoomed (Engine st m) c) st' st
        (bound at Test.hs:23:10)
      zoom :: LensLike' (Zoomed (Engine st m) c) st' st
              -> Engine st m c -> Engine st' m c
        (bound at Test.hs:23:5)
    In the first argument of `zoom', namely `l'
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `zoom l'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works for me, also GHC 7.8.3.  However, look more carefully at the error message:

```
Test.hs:22:10:
    Could not deduce (mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
                        st' (Engine st' m))
```

The explicit package identifiers like `mtl-2.1.3.1` aren't usually included in errors.  When they *are*, it means that GHC has loaded two different versions of the package, with equally named but different types and classes.  In this case, one is probably used by `lens` and the other directly by your module.

Cabal sandboxes is one way of avoiding this (they ensure consistent package versions).

Comment: Cabal sandboxes will probably help, but they in no way ensure consistent package versions. You can get all the same problems in a sandbox that you can get outside one if you try hard enough. People just generally use them for less stuff, so they get less polluted.

Comment: @DanielWagner They don't? I don't actually know since I've never had enough problems to start using them (my projects usually end up in a single file), but they seemed to be what everyone was suggesting, so I added a short note about them. Except right now "everyone" might be shifting to stack, I guess.